# Login form not submitting while using submitFormHandler ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a single page application where I'm trying to create a separate login page which would eventually redirect the authenticated user to the main application but my submitFormHandler is not getting invoked. The point of authentication is not for access to the main site(App.jsx) but instead for visibility of the NavMenu.

When I had the LoginForm and Login component in App.jsx all was working but it was still in the form of a SPA which wasn't what I was wanting. I moved things around and found that rendering the login and default site(App) with a  in the DOM did what I wanted, but now I have this current issue.

Just to get things clear, I'm a complete novice in React and have never tried routing directly in the DOM.

My code:

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./index.css"

let apiUrl;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  apiUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/api/v1";
} else {
  apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1";
}
axios.defaults.baseURL = apiUrl;

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route 
        exact path="/login"
        render={(props) =>
          <div>
            <Login />
          </div>
        }
      />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById("root"));

reportWebVitals();
```

Login.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { authenticate } from '../modules/auth';
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    renderLoginForm: false,
    authenticated: false,
    message: ""
  }

  onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await authenticate(
      e.target.email.value,
      e.target.password.value
    );
    if (response.authenticated) {
      this.setState({ authenticated: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ message: response.message, renderLoginForm: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { renderLoginForm, authenticated, message } = this.state;
    let renderLogin;
    // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
    switch (true) {
      case renderLogin && !authenticated:
        renderLogin = <LoginForm submitFormHandler={this.onLogin} />;
        break;
      case !renderLoginForm && !authenticated:
        renderLogin = (
          <>
            <button
              id="login-button"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ renderLoginForm: true })}
            >
              Login
            </button>
            <p id="message">{message}</p>
          </>
        );
        break;
      case authenticated:
        renderLogin = (
          <p id="welcome-message">
            You are logged in as{" "}
            {JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("credentials")).uid}.
          </p>
        );
        break;
    }

    return (
      <>
        {renderLogin}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

LoginForm.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Form, Container, Message, MenuItem } from "semantic-ui-react";

const LoginForm = ({ submitFormHandler }) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={submitFormHandler} id="login-form">
          <Form.Input
            icon="user"
            iconPosition="left"
            placeholder="email"
            label="Email:"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="login-email"
            required
          />

          <Form.Input
            icon="lock"
            iconPosition="left"
            placeholder="password"
            label="Password:"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            id="login-password"
            required
          />
          <Button id="login-submit" type="submit" content="Submit" primary />
        </Form>
      </Container>

      <Container>
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Link to="/register" id="register">
              Don't have an account yet? Sign up now!
            </Link>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>

        {message && (
          <Message id="onlogin-message" color="red">
            {message}
          </Message>
        )}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

App.jsx:

```
/* eslint-disable default-case */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// Component Imports
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import SideBar from "./components/SideBar";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Preferences from "./components/Preferences";
import DisplayWizard from "./components/DisplayWizard";
// import InputFields from "./components/InputFields";

// Module Imports
import { authenticate } from "./modules/auth";

// Icon Imports
import AppsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Apps";
import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import StoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Store";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import VpnKeyIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VpnKey";
import HistoryIcon from "@material-ui/icons/History";
import SettingsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Settings";
import DriveEtaIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DriveEta";
import MenuBookIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MenuBook";
import BusinessIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Business";
import LocalParkingIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LocalParking";
import FormatListBulletedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FormatListBulleted";
import SupervisorAccountIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SupervisorAccount";

function onClick(e, item) {
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(item, null, 2));
}

// Menu List Items
const items = [
  { name: "home", label: "Home", Icon: HomeIcon },
  "divider",
  {
    name: "manage",
    label: "Manage",
    Icon: AppsIcon,
    items: [
      { name: "my cars", label: "My Cars", Icon: DriveEtaIcon, onClick },
      { name: "inventory", label: "Inventory", Icon: StoreIcon, onClick },
      { name: "past orders", label: "Past Orders", Icon: HistoryIcon, onClick },
      {
        name: "parking spots",
        label: "Parking Spots",
        Icon: LocalParkingIcon,
        onClick,
      },
    ],
  },
  "divider",
  { name: "reports", label: "Reports", Icon: MenuBookIcon },
  "divider",
  {
    name: "stages",
    label: "Stages",
    Icon: FormatListBulletedIcon,
    items: [
      { name: "workshop", label: "Workshop", onClick },
      { name: "panelshop", label: "Panelshop", onClick },
    ],
  },
  "divider",
  {
    name: "admin",
    label: "Admin",
    Icon: SupervisorAccountIcon,
    items: [
      {
        name: "create new login",
        label: "Create new login",
        Icon: VpnKeyIcon,
        onClick,
      },
      {
        name: "set company/dealership",
        label: "Set Company/Dealership",
        Icon: BusinessIcon,
        onClick,
      },
      { name: "edit flow", label: "Edit Flow", Icon: CreateIcon, onClick },
      {
        name: "delete previous order",
        label: "Delete Previous Order",
        Icon: DeleteIcon,
        onClick,
      },
      {
        name: "set default options",
        label: "Set Default Options",
        Icon: CreateIcon,
        onClick,
      },
    ],
  },
  "divider",
  {
    name: "settings",
    label: "Settings",
    Icon: SettingsIcon,
    items: [
      { name: "profile", label: "Profile", onClick },
      { name: "preferences", label: "Preferences", onClick },
    ],
  },
];



class App extends Component {
  state = {
    regnum: "",
    ordernum: "",
    make: "nissan",
    model: "",
    year: "",
    color: "",
    mileage: "",
    // renderLoginForm: false,
    // authenticated: false,
    // message: "",
  };
    
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="App" id="">
          <div className="wrapper">
            {/* {renderLogin} */}
          </div>
          <Header />
          <DisplayWizard onChangeHandler={this.onChangeHandler} />
          <SideBar items={items} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If need be, I can upload the old code before I made the changes.
Thanks for any replies and help in advance, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: `onChangeHandler ` i don't see you are using this anywhere . How are you changing your form values ?

Comment: in Login,jsx, Please convert this renderLogin = <LoginForm submitFormHandler={this.onLogin} />;  to renderLogin = <LoginForm submitFormHandler={this.onLogin.bind(this)} />;

Comment: It is not needed to `bind` because he is using an arrow function .

Comment: @Shyam onChangeHandler was for my InputFields component which I didn't include here. I was purely using submitFormHandler

Answer (score 0):

Alright the problem was just a typo:

```
  case renderLogin && !authenticated:
```

Instead it should be:

```
  case renderLoginForm && !authenticated:
```